# Problem with Grails Unit Test

Tags: grails, junit

I have the next test:

```
void testRellenar() {
    Minibar m = new Minibar(categoria: 'Alta')
    Hotel h = new Hotel(precioIndividual: 40, precioDoble: 70, precioCamaSupletoria: 10, tasaNormal: 1, tasaAlta: 2, tasaBusiness: 1.3, tarifaLlamadaInternacional: 0.5, tarifaLlamadaNacional: 0.2, cantidadCerveza: 4, cantidadAgua:4, cantidadVino: 2, cantidadRefresco: 4, cantidadAlcohol: 4)
    Bebida b1 = new Bebida(tipo:"Tercio de Cerveza", precio:2)
    Bebida b2 = new Bebida(tipo:"Agua", precio:1.40)
    Bebida b3 = new Bebida(tipo:"Refresco", precio:2)
    Bebida b4 = new Bebida(tipo:"Vino", precio:10.50)
    Bebida b5 = new Bebida(tipo:"Alcohol", precio:5.20)
    def testInstances = [m]
    mockDomain(Minibar, testInstances)
    mockDomain(Hotel, [h])
    mockDomain(Bebida, [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5])
    h.save()
    b1.save()
    b2.save()
    b3.save()
    b4.save()
    b5.save()

    def srv = new MinibarService()
    srv.rellenarMinibar(m)
    def tipob = "Refresco"
    def resultado = srv.obtenerBebidaDisponible(m, "Refresco")

    assertNotSame resultado,0

}
```

But i obtain the next error:

> No signature of method:
>   org.uca.sanxer2011.services.MinibarService.obtenerBebidaDisponible()
>   is applicable for argument types:
>   (org.uca.sanxer2011.domain.application.Minibar,
>   java.lang.String) values:
>   [org.uca.sanxer2011.domain.application.Consumibles
>   : 1, Refresco]

The service obtenerBebidaDisponible() is:

```
def obtenerBebidaDisponible(Minibar minibar, String tipo) {
    def bebida = minibar.bebidas.find{ it.bebida.tipo == tipo }
    return bebida.cantidadDisponible
}
```

The domain Minibar is:

```
class Minibar extends Consumibles {

    static hasMany = [bebidas:Bebida_Minibar]
    static belongsTo = [habitacion:Habitacion]
    String categoria;

    static constraints = {
        categoria(inList:['Business', 'Alta', 'Normal'])
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'minibar'
        categoria column: 'categoria'
        bebidasDisponibles column: 'bebidas_disponibles_id'
        bebidasConsumidas column: 'bebidas_consumidas_id'
        habitacion column: 'habitacion_id'
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to show the method signature for the obtenerBebidaDisponible method in your service. Is it just a typo?

Comment: I put this code more up.

Comment: Can it be that you have two `Minibar` classes? What if you try `grails clean`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mockDomain()` **before** (not after) you create instances of domain classes - it creates a different `Class` for mocked domain class.

Plus, you don't have to provide second parameter to `mockDomain()`.

Comment: Hello, the result is the same.

Comment: I put in the first line mockDomain(Minibar) . but the result is the same: No signature of method: org.uca.sanxer2011.services.MinibarService.obtenerBebidaDisponible() is applicable for argument types: (org.uca.sanxer2011.domain.application.Minibar, java.lang.String) values: [org.uca.sanxer2011.domain.application.Consumibles : null, Refresco]

Comment: Did you remove the second parameter of `mockDomain()`?

Comment: Yes, i put mockDomain befores the instance and Minibar is null, in all examples is after